# Gestionar peticiones de gran volumen en Windows Azure

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, azure

¿Que tal comunidad? Tengo la siguiente duda; Estamos desarrollando un proyecto y tenemos una aplicación web hecha en asp mvc y aplicaciones en android y IOS.

Muchas de las funciones que hace la plataforma movil se hacen por medio de la web via services de tipo rest.
¿Qué pasaría si el volumen de peticiones aumenta para la aplicación web? Estamos tratando de resolver ese problema con azure pero no sabemos muy bien como debemos de estructurar los proyectos o que debemos usar concretamente. Algo que estuve leyendo son los cloud services mas o menos nos da una idea pero no estamos seguros. 
¿Qué sería lo mas recomendable para usar en azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se trata de una aplicacion movile y usas servicio deberias evaluar implementar Azure Movile Service

[Movile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/services/app-service/mobile/)

Analiza el ultimo punto donde menciona:

> Escalado automático para satisfacer sus necesidades empresariales

Ademas del estalado proporciona otras ventajas como servicio push, recomiendo evalues la implementacion suando .net como backend (aunque podrias hacerlo con nodejs si te animas)

[Work with the .NET backend server SDK for Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/)